# NodeJS create pdf from template, serve it for the download then delete file

Tags: node.js, express

I've problems following the steps described in the title. I'm using Express and dynamic-html-pdf to generate the pdf from a HBS template.

```
    var html = fs.readFileSync('./app/pdf/template.html', 'utf8');

    router.post("/download", function (req, res) {
        var config = req.body;
        var options = {
            format: "A4",
            orientation: "portrait",
            border: "5mm"
        };
        var document = {
            template: html,
            context: {
                options: {
                    brand: config.brand,
                    imgSrc: config.img,
                    modelName: config.modelName,
                    modelDescription: config.modelDescription
                }
            },
            path: "assets/output/"+fileName+".pdf"
        };

        var hostedFile = "/assets/output/"+fileName+".pdf";

        pdf.create(document, options).then(function() {
            res.download(hostedFile, fileName + '.pdf', function() {
                fs.unlink(hostedFile, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.toString());
                    } else {
                        console.warn(hostedFile + ' deleted');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
     });
```

What's wrong with this? It returns me this console stack and the browser says `Download failed (No file)`

```
[Tue Mar 13 2018 13:41:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /assets/output/my_file.pdf" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"
[Tue Mar 13 2018 13:41:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /assets/output/my_file.pdf" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't believe this is enough code to give you assistance, please give enough code to duplicate the error.

Comment: updated, is it enough or do you need something different?

Comment: Can not to delete file and see whether the file download is successful ?

Comment: how do you see if the file download is successful?

Comment: I know it's been a while, so you may have solved this already, but I noticed that in one path you start it with a slash and the other you don't, so I'm wondering if it's trying to read from a different location from where it wrote. Did you verify that the file exists in the expected place on the server?